# Can I use OAuth/OpenID Connect for registration/signin without redirecting to the browser?

Tags: azure, oauth, azure-ad-b2c

I have a desktop application with a login and registration screens.
I have moved to handle its identity needs via Azure AD B2C.
I am wondering whether it is possible to use OAuth/OpenID Connect features without having to be redirected to the browser? Any links?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Native apps use ROPC flow
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-ropc-policy?tabs=app-reg-ga&pivots=b2c-custom-policy

For web apps, the closest option is embedded in an iframe.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/embedded-login?pivots=b2c-custom-policy

Comment: Thanks @Jas. I have a follow-up question:
Is it possible to handle registration using the ROPC flow? Registration, not login.

Comment: For registration you must use Graph API to create the account. Then subsequently make an ROPC call to login the user.

Comment: Thanks @Jas, for the great help!

Comment: And I guess to handle social logins (Google, FB, etc...), it has to open a browser window? No way around that, right?

Comment: Yep, for social providers, you need to follow their own restrictions, all of them require a web view.